# Which is a light weight and easy to use editor for creating web graphics?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, images, software-recommendation

I currently use Photoshop for most of my web site graphics work. My work involves simple cropping, resizing and changing formats. I feel Photoshop is an overkill for my simple work.

Can anyone suggest a better editor for web graphics that is light and easy to use?

The software is for use on Windows 7/XP.

Comment: for what platform?

Comment: Imagemagick is better for this kind of work, but without a gui ;)

Comment: How can photoshop be an 'overkill' to your work? It does what is needs to do, it's not like it exports every picture complete with glitter stamps and added .gifs. Please go into a bit more detail on what you actually want.

Comment: Just about any raster image editor is capable of the things you list.. unless you need CMYK support - then you may as well stick with Photoshop.

Answer (score 1):

An obvious option is Gimp, it is free and very complete program. https://www.gimp.org/

For batch actions of croping, resizing (and sharpening) and changing formats, a good option is irfanview. http://www.irfanview.com/ (recognizes a ton of file formats)

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for cropping, resizing and changing formats the Paint will be the best in-built tool to go for. But the problem is that, it reduces image quality and does not support alpha transparent .PNG images.

So, the next best light-weight tool to go for would be [Paint.NET](https://www.getpaint.net/download.html). It work great will all types of images.

And obviously, the last and the best tool is [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/downloads/). It is free, feature-rich, high quality and also light-weight.

---

**EDIT:**

Honorable mentions include **Inkscape**. An open-source and light-weight vector graphics editor similar to Adobe Illustrator, Corel Draw, etc.

Comment: I find Paint.NET simpler to use than GIMP nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative that I find very intuitive is [Sketch app](https://www.sketchapp.com/). I use it for all my design and mock-up work as well as some other simple vector graphics. But this is my highly subjective personal view =)